# Which all data structures can I use to satisfy the needs mentioned below?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

I want to implement a DS which contains a set if numbers {x0, x1, ... , xn}.

**Init(n)** - sets a numbers x0 = x1 = ... = xn = 0. **O(n)** worst case.

**Get(i)** - returns the value of xi. **O(log n)** worst case.

**Add(d, i, j)** - adds to all numbers: xi , ... , xj the value "d" (supposed that i <= j). **O(log n)** worst case.

I want just an idea how can I implement these DS in the mentioned time complexities. Thank you.

Comment: That much isn't true, I don't think. You could easily make a data type that represents a value applied to a range, and represent value as a list of these value ranges rather than an actual number in memory. From there it's easy to implement `Add(d,i,j)` in `O(1)`. However, this approach doesn't allow for a quick `get(i)`. The problem seems to be doing *both* get and add in O(log(n)).

Comment: "From there it's easy to implement Add(d,i,j) in O(1)" Once it works. Then if you want to add to a different range overlapping over the first, how many more?

Comment: @Obaf This is unrelated, but I don't have any other way to get in touch with you: I posted https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2859580/class-of-fractal-curves-derived-from-recursion-on-the-base-2-representation-of-t based on your question about the recursion with the missing base case that got deleted.

Comment: @zwol thank you so much, it will help me, I will follow the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by building a tree, for example the complete binary tree of depth d, where 2^d >= n >= 2^(d-1) so for 5..8 numbers

```
       g
   e       f
 a   b   c   d
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Now associate a number with every leaf and every internal node.

To extract a value, add together all the numbers on the path to the leaf - O(log n) time.

To add a value to a range of numbers, work from the top and add that value to nodes whose descendants are all in that range and whose parents have some numbers in that range and some numbers not in that range. E.g. to add to 3..7 add to b, c, and 7. There should be at most O(log n) of such numbers because you shouldn't have to update more than two nodes on each level.

Comment: Ok, suppose that I want to have repeated additions with overlapping ranges. Have the following "addition program" for an example (one-based indexing): `[1..1]+1, [1..2]+2, [2..3]+3, [3..4]+4, [4..5]+5, [5..6]+6, [6..7]+7,[7..8]+8` (where `[i..j]+x` means `add(x,i,j)`). How many additions in total your algo does? If you feel it's unfair because you only picked 1..8, feel free to expand until you think it's clear your algo shows an advantage. (it is the subsequent addtions in overlapping ranges that I don't get from your explanation. As I also don't understand as how do you implement `get(i)`)

Comment: The idea is when we are talking about j - i = constant , it's easy to do the addition in O(log n) (k times of O(log n), but the main idea is how to deal with the problem when j-i  is O(n) lets suppose n/2, so the solution is to fix the addition high enough to reach the O(log n). it's okay thank you.